# Displayining multiple bash output horizontally

Tags: linux, bash

I have 4 important services running on my machine which I want to see them all the time. I have this simple bash script running as bash profile.

```
echo
PROC="nginx mysql php-fpm pptpd"
for p in $PROC
do
  ps cax | grep $p > /dev/null

  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo -e "\e[92m$p running\e[0m"
  else
    echo -e "\e[101m$p IS NOT RUNNING \e[0m"
  fi

done
echo
```

The out put of this script is:

```
nginx running
mysql running
php-fpm running
pptpd running
```

How can I make it like this?

```
nginx running - mysql running - php-fpm running - pptpd running
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `printf` or add the `-n` flag to echo.

### POSIX Compliant Refactor without ProcTools

```
#!/bin/sh

showstatus() {
  echo
  while [ "$1" ]; do
    if ps cax | grep -qF "$1"; then
      msg='\e[92m%s running\e[0m'
    else
      msg='\e[101m%s IS NOT RUNNING \e[0m'
    fi
    printf "$msg" "$1"
    shift
    [ "$1" ] && printf ' - '
  done
  echo
}
showstatus nginx mysql php-fpm pptpd
```

### POSIX Compliant Refactor with ProcTools

```
#!/bin/sh

showstatus() {
  echo
  while [ "$1" ]; do
    if pkill -0 "$1"; then
      msg='\e[92m%s running\e[0m'
    else
      msg='\e[101m%s IS NOT RUNNING \e[0m'
    fi
    printf "$msg" "$1"
    shift
    [ "$1" ] && printf ' - '
  done
  echo
}
showstatus nginx mysql php-fpm pptpd
```

Answer (score 1):

Build the status lines first into an array, and then print the array:

```
status=()
for p in $PROC
do
  if ps cax | grep -q $p; then
    status+=( " \e[92m$p running\e[0m " )
  else
    status+=( " \e[101m$p IS NOT RUNNING \e[0m " )
  fi
done
(IFS=-; echo -e "${status[*]}")
```

`${status[*]}` expands to every element in the array joined by the first character of `IFS`, which I set to `-` earlier. Note that I used a subshell `(IFS=-; echo ...)`, so that changing `IFS` doesn't affect the rest of the script.

Other notes:

```
ps cax | grep $p > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
```

Can be combined to:

```
if ps cax | grep -q $p; then
```

Which is much more concise and readable. You could also consider using `pgrep` instead.